# How to load angular date filter on success of REST call or after an event broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a REST api which gives me date-format (along with other data). I want this date-format to be used in my custom date filter, so that I can use this filter in my view.

My view is something like this.

`<span>{{vm.filters.fromDate | dateFilter}}</span>`

My filter is like this.

```
.filter('dateFilter', function( $filter, commonService ) {
      var dateFormat = commonService.getDateFormat();
      return function( inputDate ) {
          return $filter('date')( inputDate, dateFormat );
      };
 })
```

There is another setter for date-format in commonService `commonService.setDateFormat( dateFormat )` which executes on success of the REST call.

But in my case, filter is executing before I get the response from api, so it couldn't get any date-format from commonService through `commonService.getDateFormat()` in filter implementation. Hence wrong date-format is reflecting on UI.

What is the best way to execute/ load a angular filter on success of something or on broadcast of an event?

Comment: can you post the code for `commonService.getDateFormat()`? if this function also makes a REST request, you'll need to use `promise` so that the latter code only runs after this REST request is completed.

Comment: No this just returns the `this.dateFormat` which was set during setDateFormat() method. On success of backend REST api call, I am setting the `dateFormat` in `commonService` so that I can use it later though getter.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your filter as [$stateful](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#stateful-filters):

```
.filter('dateFilter', function () {
    var dateFormat = commonService.getDateFormat();;
    function dateFilter(input) {
        if (dateFormat) {
            return $filter('date')( inputDate, dateFormat );
        } else {
            return "---"; //some placeholder until format is loaded
        }
     }
     dateFilter.$stateful = true; //important
     return dateFilter;
});
```

But there is better option (I don't know if it possible in your case).

If you are in control of your backend, you could render some contants into your main view as javascript object. Then you could inject it into your application using `angular.constant`.

If you write more about your backend, then I could extend my anwser.

## Other Solution

If you don't want to use stateful filters, you could also make filter with pattern passed as parameter.

```
.filter("dateFilter", function() { // register new filter
    return function(input, pattern) { // filter arguments
         ....
    };
});
```

The you could pass pattern as argument for filter:

```
{{ vm.filters.fromDate | dateFilter: vm.pattern}}
```

In this case angular would now that if parameter changes, then filter needs to be updated.

Comment: I just read stateful filters are not recommended. Can you explain the `angular.constant` way? In my app, after successful login, I call a `settings service` from `header-controller` where I get the date-format in response. And I am setting the same in commonService through a setter method.

Comment: Are you using php, java, node ... on server side ? Please extend you anwser how are you getting your date format.

Comment: Backend is Java, but I don't have much control over that.

My REST api - http://localhost:9000/apis/dashboard/settings

Dummy Response - {'dateFormat' - 'dd-MM-yyyy','prop1':'val1',.......}

Answer (score 1):

You can call commonService.getDateFormat() in the REST success and pass it's value 'Date Format' to the filter, here is a code sample.

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])
            .filter('dateFilter', function($filter) {
                return function(inputDate, dateFormat) {
                    return $filter('date')(inputDate, dateFormat);
                };
            })
            .controller('AppCtrl', appCtrl);

        function appCtrl($timeout) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.init = function() {
              // fake service callback
              $timeout(function () {
                vm.datetime = new Date();
                vm.dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
              },1000);

            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp">
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
        <p>{{ vm.datetime | dateFilter: vm.dateFormat }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where did you use your filter `dateFilter`?

Comment: oh sorry, i edited the answer, I am using it here <p>{{ vm.datetime | dateFilter: vm.dateFormat }}</p>

Comment: I understand that if I pass `vm.dateFormat` as parameter to custom filter, it will execute again when newValue of `vm.dateFormat` will change and `$digest` cycle will run. But is there any way to re execute the filter if I don't pass a scope variable to my custom filter like I have shown in my question?